# Hibernate memory leak. Single instance of ConcurrentHashMap$Node[] takes 98% of heap space

Tags: java, hibernate, memory-leaks

I have a great problem with something alike memory leak caused by Hibernate or my code that uses Hibernate (see tree from MAT below).

Could you guys suggest where should I go with that? 
Might it be a Hibernate bug and I just need to update to newer ver? 
Or does below suggest that I don't close sessions? 
Or do I create multiple Factories? 
Or is it some unnecessary caching I should disable?

I would be very thankful for any help.

Screenshot from MAT:

[image]

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Looking at SessionFactoryRegistry class the concurrentHasMap is added to everytime you create a sessionFactory.
i guess you are creating a new one everytime instead of reusing the same